# GWT and multi-module maven

Tags: maven, gwt

I've a gwt project with 2 maven modules: 
FE and BE, 
FE generates a war and has only gwt code BE generates a jar file and has only backend code
i've also the parent pom.
The FE pom has the BE dependency.
The project works fine and from FE call async method and get simple String from BE.

The problem is when i want call async method with MyDTO.java and not a simple String:
under shared directory in FE add MyDTO.java, 
BE should instantiate MyDTO but if add FE dependency in BO pom i've cyclic reference error!

In .gwt.xml file could add ?

```
 <source path="--package from other maven module.."/>
```

thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

You should create a second BE.gwt.xml (which points to the shared code) and inherit the new BE.gwt.xml in you existing FE.gwt.xml.

Comment: add BE.gwt.xml in BE and add  <inherits name="com.myproj.BE"/> in FE.gwt.xml but i've this error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) on project fe: GWT Module com.myproj.BE not found in project sources or resources. -> [Help 1]

Comment: i've solved adding in FE.pom:

     <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>